# Swift - How to filter through multiple keywords using UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, search, uisearchcontroller

I have a UISearchController that when a user enters text, it searches through the objects. However the user can only search for a single keyword, I want them to search through multiple keywords.

Model:

```
struct DiagnosisDetails: Codable {
    let diagnosisCodeId: Int
    let diagnosisMappingId: Int
    let diagnosisCode: String?
    let bodyRegion: String?
    let bodyPart: String?
    let bodySite: String?
}
```

Code for the search

```
 func filteredDiagnosis(for queryOrNil: String?) -> [DiagnosisDetails] {
        guard let diagnosis = self.diagnosis, let query = queryOrNil, !query.isEmpty else { return [] }
        
        let filteredDiagnosis: [DiagnosisDetails] = diagnosis.filter {
            if let bodyPart = $0.bodyPart,
               let bodySite = $0.bodySite,
               let bodyRegion = $0.bodyRegion,
               let diagnosisCode = $0.diagnosisCode {
                return (bodyPart.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased()) || bodySite.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased()) || bodyRegion.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased()) || diagnosisCode.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased()))
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        return filteredDiagnosis
    }
```

How can I have the user search for multiple keywords?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your searching logic, by creating helper string of diagnosis fields you want to query, and then find any substring that matches it.

First of all, create function that returns "master search string" from Diagnosis:

```
struct DiagnosisDetails: Codable, Hashable {
    let diagnosisCodeId: Int
    let diagnosisMappingId: Int
    let diagnosisCode: String?
    let bodyRegion: String?
    let bodyPart: String?
    let bodySite: String?

    func getSearchString() -> String {
        let bPart = bodyPart ?? ""
        let bSite = bodySite ?? ""
        let bRegion = bodyRegion ?? ""
        let dCode = diagnosisCode ?? ""
        return bPart + bSite + bRegion + dCode
    }
}
```

Then simply search function as follows:

```
func filteredDiagnosis(for queryOrNil: String?) -> [DiagnosisDetails] {
    guard let diagnosis = self.diagnosis, let query = queryOrNil, !query.isEmpty else { return [] }

    return diagnosis.filter({
        return $0.getSearchString().range(of: query, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })
}
```

---

UPD
Filter function for multi-words search string: the idea is simple - split search query into words, filter diagnosis array for every word matching and combine all answers using set

```
func filteredDiagnosis(for queryOrNil: String?) -> [DiagnosisDetails] {
    guard let diagnosis = self.diagnosis, let query = queryOrNil, !query.isEmpty else { return [] }

    let searchWords = query.components(separatedBy: " ").filter({$0 != ""})
    var filterResults = Set<DiagnosisDetails>()

    for word in searchWords {
        let wordResult = diagnosis.filter {$0.getSearchString().range(of: word, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
        for res in wordResult { filterResults.insert(res) }
    }

    return Array(filterResults)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however this still does not fix the issue I have. the issue is after a user enters the space bar, the search bar does not look for the text after the space. so it only looks the first word.

Comment: @isaacthedev please check updated answer, with this kind of function you will have an ability to use search string like "code1 region2 site3" etc